# lower bound on an ellipse

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Is there anyway to estimate the lower bound for $Re(zP'(z)/P(z))=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{z}{z-z_k}$ on an ellipse where $P(z)=\prod_{k=1}^n(z-z_k)$ with $z_k, 1\leq k\leq n$ lying entirely within the ellipse?  The equivalent question for the unit circle has very straightforward answer $1/2. $